# SQL - Use a reference of a CTE to another CTE

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

Is it possible in SQL use a reference inside a Common Table Expression inside another C.T.E in the same query? Here there is an example:

```
WITH CT1 AS (SELECT * FROM T),
     CT2 AS (SELECT * FROM CT1)

SELECT * FROM CT2;
```

I tried this in SQLite3 and it works, I just wanted to know if it's part of standard SQL. Any advices concerning this argument will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: FWIW, it works in Postgres as well, and I can't think of any reason this *wouldn't* be in the standard.

Comment: I can confirm that it will work in Postgres, Oracle an SQL Server. This is how it was defined in the SQL standard.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if I can define them in a random order? In this example can I define ct2 before ct1? In sqlite3 the result is positive

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27146764/905902 , for  an application of such "chained" CTEs

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here are three important properties of CTEs:

- You can refer to a CTE in subsequent CTEs or in the main body of the query.
- You can refer to any given CTE multiple times.
- The CTE can be used in a `from` clause at any level of nesting within other subqueries.

The CTEs -- as with everything in SQL -- need to be defined before they are used.  So, you cannot define them in random order.

This is the standard definition of CTEs and does a good job of explaining how they are used across databases.  Those three properties are key ways that they differ from subqueries.

Comment: Can I reference a non-recursive CTE in a recursive CTE? I just tried `WITH my_non_rec_cte AS ( ... ), RECURSIVE my_rec_cte AS (...) SELECT * FROM my_rec_cte` and I get a syntax error near `RECURSIVE my_rec_cte AS ...`.