# How to re-use one CTE in another CTE in jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, common-table-expression, jooq

In jOOQ am re-using a CTE in a later CTE. I am trying to summarise student completion records by year and school. I am using jOOQ 3.11.2 and postgres 9.4.

I have working SQL code. However in jOOQ, I am getting null values returned.

This appears to be a problem with how I am re-using one CTE in a later CTE.

At first, I thought it might be a problem with the use of count(). From the manual, it looks like count() is being used correctly. As a test, I removed all reference to count() in the query and still get the same error.

I could not find examples of reusing or chaining CTEs in jOOQ. Easy enough in SQL, as shown here: [SQL - Use a reference of a CTE to another CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204824/sql-use-a-reference-of-a-cte-to-another-cte) but I haven't got the hang of it in jOOQ.

When run in debug mode on Intellij, I see an error that the **select()** statement cannot be evaluated in the second CTE.

```
Cannot evaluate org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.toString()
```

Here is a minimal example showing what I am doing.

```
 CommonTableExpression<Record4<String, String, String, Year>> cteOne = name("CteOne")
    .fields("SCHOOL","STUDENT_NAME", "COURSE_COMPLETED", "YEAR_COMPLETED")
    .as(
            select( a.NAME.as("SCHOOL")
                    , a.STUDENT_NAME
                    , a.COURSE_DESCRIPTION.as("courseCompleted"),
                    , a.YEAR_COMPLETED 
                    )
                    .from(a)
                    .orderBy(a.YEAR_COMPLETED)
    );

CommonTableExpression<Record3<String, Year, Integer >> cteCounts = name("cteCounts")

    .fields("SCHOOL", "YEAR_COMPLETED", "NUM_COMPLETED" )

    .as( with(cteOne)
                    .select(
                            , field(name("cteOne","SCHOOL"), String.class)
                            , field(name("cteOne","YEAR_COMPLETED"), Year.class)
                            , count().as("NUM_COMPS_LOGGED")
                    )
                    .from(cteOne)
                    .groupBy(
                            field(name("cteCompsList","YEAR_COMPLETED"), Year.class)
                          , field(name("cteOne","SCHOOL"), String.class)
                    )
                    .orderBy(
                            field(name("cteCompsList","YEAR_COMPLETED"), Year.class)
                          , field(name("cteOne","SCHOOL"), String.class)
                    )
    );
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction on this?

Answer (score 2):

Just like in your plain SQL version of your query, your `cteCounts` should not have a `with(cteOne)` clause:

```sql
WITH 
  cteOne (columns...) AS (select...),
  cteCounts (columns...) AS (select referencing cteOne, no "with cteOne" here...)
SELECT ...
FROM ...
```

Remove it and your query should be fine

Comment: Thankyou. I deleted the with( cteOne) clause & got an error that the SQL produced by jooq doesn't have a reference to cteOne. I tried other places within cteOne such as:  ```with(cteOne).name(...)``` then ```name(...).with(cteOne).fields(...)``` then ```name(...).fields(...).with(cteOne).as(...)```. Intellij says that none are correct.
Doing something like: ```Result<?> result2 = create().with(t1) .with(t2) .select( ...).from(t1, t2).fetch()```;  works fine,  but doesn't the cteCounts also need a ```with()``` somewhere in the definition of the CTE?

Comment: @peterJ: Thanks a lot for your comment. Would you mind asking a new question? The Stack Overflow comment formatting makes it difficult to follow what you might've been doing since my answer.

Comment: yes, the comment format makes it hard to follow. I have posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59271846/jooq-error-relation-cte-does-not-exist

Comment: @peterJ: Thanks. Will look into it in a bit

Comment: @LukasEder Isn't it a case that some dialects support [nested cte](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6c34a51c4824f2a500da9596e35aaa03)? Could you post the "plain" SQL version how this "non-working" query would look like?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: I don't think the OP was going to nest CTE. I'll be happy to answer your own, separate question on Stack Overflow...